# Does stripslashes remove unwanted slashes from contact form fields?

Tags: php

I would like to use stripslashes in order to prevent or remove forward and backslashes from being typed or entered into my contact form fields.

Would this work if I add it to the Post statement like so:

```
<?php

if($_POST) {

   $fName = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['fName'], ENT_COMPAT | ENT_XHTML | $encoding = 'UTF-8'));

   $fEmail = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['fEmail'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XHTML | $encoding = 'UTF-8')));

   $fComments = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['fComments'], ENT_NOQUOTES | ENT_XHTML | $encoding = 'UTF-8'));
?>
```

Or is there a way to prevent or remove both forward and backslashes using *preg_match*?

Comment: There is not a single acceptable reason to use `stripslashes` or `addslashes` nowadays.

Comment: @DeeRoy why don't you try ? `echo $fName,"<br>\n",$_POST['fName'];` and see for yourself.

Comment: Did you try running that code to see if it worked as you wanted or not? Could you not just use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

Answer (score 2):

This will **not** prevent or remove forward and backslashes from being **typed, entered, or submitted** to your form. It *will* remove them from the form's POST data after the data has been received.

To prevent the user from **entering** or **typing** in backslashes or forward slashes before submitting the form, you will need to implement a javascript solution.

Blessings

Comment: Hi @Chris B, what I really wanted was to secure the contact form, by having the slashes removed before the message was received. Are you sure that stripslashes affects both types of slashes?